# Custom TextField Designs Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to achieve the design below but I don't know how to customize this, am still a newbie in Flutter.

I know how to use `TextFields` but don't know how to go around this :

[image]

Comment: Refer to the documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html especially, take a look at the InputDecoration part: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html. You can customize most of the things using InputDecoration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                filled: true,
                hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                hintText: "Email",
                fillColor: Colors.white70),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          TextField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                filled: true,
                hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                hintText: "Password",
                fillColor: Colors.white70),
          )
        ]));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Lutaaya Huzaifah Idris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6687699/lutaaya-huzaifah-idris) Refer to the documentation as specified by [Afridi Kayal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12636223/afridi-kayal) in comments for more customization.

```
   Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 20),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20,10,20,10),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Email",
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 20),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20,10,20,10),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Password",
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        obscureText: true,
      ),
    ),
```

Output:

[image]