# How can I apply a decoration to a TextField in Flutter that looks like the one in the provided image?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i use stack to solve the problem?
Is there a way to achieve the custom decoration of a TextField in Flutter shown in the attached image?
What is the best approach to implement the decorative TextField shown in the image for a Flutter app?

[image]

Comment: Check flutter documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html) or read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447218/custom-textfield-designs-flutter) stack overflow question. In summary, you need to change the text field decoration.

Answer (score 0):

You can add label inside field's inputDecoration  , and change its behavior to always shown , then change the border to be underline border and change its color and width
there is a code :

```
class CustomFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String hint, label;
  const CustomFormField(
      {super.key,
      required this.controller,
      required this.hint,
      required this.label});
  @override
  _CustomFormFieldState createState() => _CustomFormFieldState();
}

class _CustomFormFieldState extends State<CustomFormField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: widget.controller,
        decoration: _inputDecoration(widget.hint),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// the border of the field
  InputBorder _border() => UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          //width of the underline and its color
            width: 1.5, color: Colors.red.shade500, 
            style: BorderStyle.solid),
      );
  InputDecoration _inputDecoration(String hint) => InputDecoration(
      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
      filled: false,
      enabledBorder: _border(),
      focusedBorder: _border(),
      border: _border(),
      disabledBorder: _border(),
      errorBorder: _border(),
      focusedErrorBorder: _border(),
      errorStyle: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xffff99c2)),
      fillColor: Color(0xffff99c2),
      hintText: hint,
      alignLabelWithHint: true,
      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
      //label (the text above the field)
      label: Text(
        
        widget.label,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red.shade700,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20),
      ));
}
```

[image]